# IWindow: get mappable children / convert to TestObject

Tags: rft, ibm-rational

I would like to be able to dynamically extract all objects belonging to an `IWindow` and then convert them to `TestObjects`. 
I list all available `IWindows` using:

```
IWindow[] windows = root.getTopWindows();
```

The user will then select an IWindow based on its title (using `windows[i].getText()` to identify the correct title). I would then like to be able to extract all its children so that I can perform operations on them at a later stage. For TestObject instances, I can already extract all children - however how do I go from having grabbed an `IWindow` to getting the `TestObjects` that compose its user interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure whether it is possible to get TestObjects from an IWindow or to convert an IWindow to a TestObject. Maybe there is another way to find windows—via DomainTestObjects. I know it is not exactly an answer to the question, but could be something:

```
public void displayDomainsAndTopObjects()
{
    DomainTestObject[] dtos = getDomains();
    for (DomainTestObject dto : dtos)
    {
        System.out.println("--- " + dto.getName() + " ---");
        TestObject[] tos = dto.getTopObjects();
        for (TestObject to : tos)
        {
            System.out.println(to.getDescriptiveName());
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe you can find a workaround that way? E.g. displaying all open browsers:

```
public void displayBrowsers()
{
    DomainTestObject[] dtos = getDomains();

    List<DomainTestObject> htmlDomains = new ArrayList<DomainTestObject>();
    for (DomainTestObject dto : dtos)
    {
        if (dto.getName().equals("Html"))
        {
            htmlDomains.add(dto);
        }
    }

    List<BrowserTestObject> browsers = new ArrayList<BrowserTestObject>();
    for (DomainTestObject htmlDomain : htmlDomains)
    {
        TestObject[] tos = htmlDomain.getTopObjects();
        for (TestObject to : tos)
        {
            if (to.getProperty(".class").equals("Html.HtmlBrowser"))
            {
                browsers.add((BrowserTestObject) to);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Found " + browsers.size() + " browsers:");
    for (BrowserTestObject browser : browsers)
    {
        System.out.println(browser.getProperty(".documentName"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Roland. This seems like a really good workaround! Just a question: what are Domains in the context of RFT?

Comment: A domain represents the object model of a supported area—e.g. Java, Html, Net, Process. `getDomains()` returns an array containing DomainTestObjects for all domains which are currently running. I think it is somewhat the most top-level object you can get to find further TestObjects in RFT.

Comment: OK, thanks. getDomains() returns only one domain named "Process". It contains no children (no mappable children, no top objects etc)...any idea what causes this?

Comment: Not really. When I run the code I get the domains Net, ActiveX, Win (with several windows), Siebel, Java, Html (with some browsers and dialogs), and Process. Running RFT 8.5.1.2 (Java) on Win7. Are you running some applications which are activated—e.g. an activated IE? Then at least the Html and Java Domains should be running.

Comment: Mhh, odd. Running RFT 8.5 on Win7 as well. Yup, I have several activated applications running...IE, a sample Java application, Notepad etc